# I can't use the Preview Browser (VS code extension)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I installed [Browser Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview), (Visual Studio Code extension), but I can't use it.

After installation I have two options:

- Browser Preview: Attach
- Browser Preview: Launch

When selecting Attach option I have the following screen:

[image: Browser Preview: Attach]

And by selecting the Launch option:

[image: Browser Preview: Launch]

I tried to configure as described in the topic 'How to change the default start url / start page?' from the [plug in page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview).

[image: configure]

I got a result with the first case.
There are 2 fields named "browser preview". I tried each one separately, and both.

I also came to view the [vs code](https://code.visualstudio.com) website.

I have also tested numerous variations such as the url of my * .html file. The file even opened but had no simultaneous update. I also tried to put http: // localhost: 3000 in the fields mentioned. I was not successful either.

I tried deleting all vs code files (including configuration files) and reinstalling everything, but I didn't solve the problem either.

I suppose the error could be in the launch.json configuration file. I am reading the [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) contained in this file, but already lost too many hours in it to not ask for help.

I will leave my html code and configuration file.

NOTE: Ignore the bad formatting of html/css. I started studying web development a short time ago.

Configuration file "launch.json":

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "browser-preview",
        "name": "Browser Preview: Attach",
        "request": "attach"
    },
    {
        "type": "browser-preview",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Browser Preview: Launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
]
}
```

```css
html{
 background-image: url("imagens/fundo.png");
}

td{
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}

a{
 color: blue;
}

table{
 background-color: #dddd;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 90px;
 width: 900px;
}

#ConteudoPrincipal{
 width: 880px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: white; 
}

#TodosOsDireitosReservados{
 
 text-align: center;
 /*margin: auto;*/
 width: 880px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.FotosStyle{
 border: 10px solid #ddd;
}

#DivFoto1{
 padding: 10px;
}

#TiituloDaPágina{
 color: #444241;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Campanhas publicitárias</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  
  <img src="imagens/capa.png">
  
  <div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td> <a href="indexs.html">HOME</a></td>
     <td>|</td>
     <td><a href="BIOGRAFIA.html">BIOGRAFIA</a></td>
     <td>|</td>
     <td><a href="CAMPANHA_PUBLICITARIAS.html">CAMPANHA PUBLICITÁRIAS</a></td>
     <td>|</td>
     <td><a href="CONTATOS.html">CONTATOS</a></td>
    </tr>
 
   </table>
  </div>

  <div id="ConteudoPrincipal">

   <div>
    <P id="TiituloDaPágina">Sobre Anna Bella</P>
   </div>
   
   <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nunc felis, tincidunt congue tellus a, finibus viverra dolor. Phasellus vel nunc vel ligula elementum cursus ut vel velit. Cras porta ullamcorper turpis quis ultricies. Donec dignissim mauris augue, eget vulputate odio commodo vitae. Phasellus et vehicula diam. Suspendisse sed nunc nec quam ornare condimentum. Cras sit amet nibh ac nibh condimentum consectetur ac id orci. Mauris ac gravida libero, non porttitor sapien. Pellentesque nec ultricies ex. Nam id arcu nibh. Mauris vitae semper orci. Curabitur maximus scelerisque quam quis hendrerit. Fusce semper accumsan lacus, id hendrerit lacus sagittis id. Phasellus iaculis mi at egestas venenatis. Nunc fermentum diam vel nunc rhoncus ultrices.</p>
   
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nunc felis, tincidunt congue tellus a, finibus viverra dolor. Phasellus vel nunc vel ligula elementum cursus ut vel velit. Cras porta ullamcorper turpis quis ultricies. Donec dignissim mauris augue, eget vulputate odio commodo vitae. Phasellus et vehicula diam. Suspendisse sed nunc nec quam ornare condimentum. Cras sit amet nibh ac nibh condimentum consectetur ac id orci. Mauris ac gravida libero, non porttitor sapien. Pellentesque nec ultricies ex. Nam id arcu nibh. Mauris vitae semper orci. Curabitur maximus scelerisque quam quis hendrerit. Fusce semper accumsan lacus, id hendrerit lacus sagittis id. Phasellus iaculis mi at egestas venenatis. Nunc fermentum diam vel nunc rhoncus ultrices.</p>
 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nunc felis, tincidunt congue tellus a, finibus viverra dolor. Phasellus vel nunc vel ligula elementum cursus ut vel velit. Cras porta ullamcorper turpis quis ultricies. Donec dignissim mauris augue, eget vulputate odio commodo vitae. Phasellus et vehicula diam. Suspendisse sed nunc nec quam ornare condimentum. Cras sit amet nibh ac nibh condimentum consectetur ac id orci. Mauris ac gravida libero, non porttitor sapien. Pellentesque nec ultricies ex. Nam id arcu nibh. Mauris vitae semper orci. Curabitur maximus scelerisque quam quis hendrerit. Fusce semper accumsan lacus, id hendrerit lacus sagittis id. Phasellus iaculis mi at egestas venenatis. Nunc fermentum diam vel nunc rhoncus ultrices.</p>
   </div>

  </div>

  
  <div id="TodosOsDireitosReservados">
   <p>Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
  </div>

 </body>


</html>
```

Comment: use [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer). Better option for static html files.

Comment: I was wearing it. But I wish I didn't have to change screens.